# How to open share dialog in mobile app if installed else in browser from my website?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, mobile, deep-linking

FB.ui share dialog works well for desktop version. It works for mobile well but opens in browser. Thats the problem. I need to open the same dialog in mobile app if installed or open in browser if not installed.
Please help me 
I am successfully able to open in twitter like this

```
twitter://post?message=" + encodeURIComponent(text)
```

I need same in fb. anybody knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37549/force-link-to-open-in-app-not-my-default-browser

Twitter/FB apps shold be able to handle catching any links related to them.
Just use normal twitter/fb links like you allways do.
If it is not working, nothing can be done, since this process in being handeled by an app, and not by webpage code.